# Is there any command for reaching file's end in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm configuring my apache server and have to reach the last few lines of my conf file many times. Is there any Vim command which would help me with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, just use: <kbd>G</kbd>.

This works in the usual way with other commands, i.e. <kbd>yG</kbd> yanks from the current line to and including the last line.
Hence, beware of <kbd>dG</kbd> unless you know <kbd>u</kbd>!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use <kbd>G</kbd> (capital`g`).

Double lower case `g` takes you to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
:$
```

It works too! But I've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

Author asked for a short way to start vim editor at last line.
Just add the arg '+' (without a lineumber, not "+123") to vim invocation, that will put your cursor down to the bottom of the file.

`vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf +`

the position does not matter, so you can also write

`vim + /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`